# COMBOBOX filtering in WPF with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, itemssource

I am developing an application using WPF mvvm approach.
I have a requirement where I have to show a list of items in a combo box for selection.
Based on some flag I need to filter out few items from the combo box for selection.

I tried to use two different items sources one with full list and another with filtered list and based on the flag I wanted to change the items source.
This does not seem to be working well. Is there any easy way to apply filters on the existing list based on some flag ?

Comment: What's not working? You need to add more details and code too which is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to do this but my personal preference is to use a `ListCollectionView` as the ItemsSource of the control displaying the filtered list, to set a filter predicate on `ListCollectionView.Filter` and to call `ListCollectionView.Refresh` when the filter parameters change.

The example below will filter a list of countries based on their continent.

Code

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Data;

public class FilteringViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Country> _countries;
    private ContinentViewModel _selectedContinent;

    public ListCollectionView CountryView { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ObservableCollection<ContinentViewModel> Continents { get; set; } 

    public FilteringViewModel()
    {
        _countries =
            new ObservableCollection<Country>(
                new[]
                    {
                        new Country() { Continent = Continent.Africa, DisplayName = "Zimbabwe" },
                        new Country() { Continent = Continent.Africa, DisplayName = "Egypt" },
                        new Country() { Continent = Continent.Europe, DisplayName = "United Kingdom" }
                    });
        CountryView = new ListCollectionView(_countries);
        CountryView.Filter = o => _selectedContinent == null || ((Country)o).Continent == _selectedContinent.Model;

        Continents = new ObservableCollection<ContinentViewModel>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Continent)).Cast<Continent>().Select(c => new ContinentViewModel { Model = c}));
    }

    public ContinentViewModel SelectedContinent
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedContinent;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedContinent = value;
            OnContinentChanged();
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedContinent");
        }
    }

    private void OnContinentChanged()
    {
        CountryView.Refresh();
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class Country
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public Continent Continent { get; set; }
}

public enum Continent
{
    [Description("Africa")]
    Africa,
    Asia,
    Europe,
    America
}

public class ContinentViewModel
{
    public Continent Model { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            return Enum.GetName(typeof(Continent), Model);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Continents}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContinent}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CountryView}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks. This approach worked for me. Thanks a lot for saving my few hours of time. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any easy way to apply filters on the existing list based on
>   some flag ?

Although your question is not clear, but I think you don't need to maintain two list just to get the filter data. You can use simple LINQ to do the filtering. Suppose if you have a ViewModel Property like

```
public IEnumerable<ComboBoxItem> Data
    {
        get ;
        set ;
    }
```

And you want to filter that based on some bool values then you can write something like

```
ViewModel.Data.ToList().Where(item => item.Status).ToList()
```

Status can be the bool based on that you want to filter your data and you can add this bool  inside your ComboBoxItem class.

Comment: But how do you associate the results as the `ItemSource` of the combo?